# Need to change my map object into json object in ArcGis javascript

Tags: dojo, arcgis

Hello there i am trying to call  PrintingTools (GPServer) - Export Web Map Task - execute  manually .

for that purpose i need to change my map object into json object (Web Map as JSON:(GPString)). this is the first argument.

is there any method to get Json object directly in Arcgis javascript 3.5 APIs ?

Comment: Or i have second option to click the Print_button half work is done but i struck on second step when PrintOut (Link button) came. so which approch i have to follow .

Comment: Check my answer .... It is working fine . I choose second option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dojo.connect(app.printer, 'onPrintComplete', function (value) {
            // window.open(value.url);
            setTimeout(FinalStep, 1000);
        });

    function PrintButton() {
        require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom"], function (query, dom) {
            var node = dom.byId("print_button");
            nl = query(".dijitButtonNode", node);
            if (nl.length > 0)
                nl[0].click();

        });        
        return false;
    }       

  function FinalStep() {
        require(["dojo/query", "dojo/dom"], function (query, dom) {
            var n2 = query(".esriPrintout", dojo.byId("print_button"));
            if (n2.length > 0) {
                n2[0].click();
                document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
            }
        });
    }
```